# How can I determine which localhost port is running?

Tags: macos, shell, command-line, terminal, localhost

I just find out that when I simply type 'localhost' in the url without anything more in the path, the browser displays a message from a local backend test project in Express that I've made days ago.

I'm trying to stop this process.

I was sure that to have started this server on port 3001 but when I try to kill it , it says that there is no process running on this port.

I tried to kill 8080 as well, but the message is still displayed.

Obviously, I refreshed the page, I tried on several different browser, even restarted my computer.

How can i determine which port is running?
How can I stop the process?

[Edit]:
Here's what I keep receiving :

```
<html><head></head><body><h1>It works!</h1>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Try `lsof -i @localhost`.

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I was looking for, so I killed every process using sudo kill -9 process_id. Unfortunately the message is still displayed.

Comment: Is it a browser message? Or a web page? Maybe refresh the browser before or whilst `lsof` is running.

Answer (score 7):

You could use `lsof`:

```
lsof -i @localhost
```

Comment: Your reply is the solution for my approach, but my issue is not resolved. Now every processes are killed but typing 'localhost' in my browser displays a message I wrote in a backend test days ago.

Comment: Did you do ctrl+r to hard refresh (clear browser cache)?

Comment: It's a message displayed in a dummy webpage sent by an Express backend test I made days ago. I tried with several browser just to be sure it was not cached , I refreshed , restart my computer ...etc

Comment: Maybe try `lsof -ni @127.0.0.1` but it should be the same. A bit out of my depth but if it's running in a VM you might need a different approach.

Comment: Indeed, it does not fix it. Not running in a VM. Thx anyway, you helped a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this command :

```
sudo lsof -nP -i4TCP:80
```

Comment: Issue is same, localhost in the url still displays the html (see edit section in the original post)

Comment: Did above command display the process listening port 80?

Comment: The above command does not display anything.

Comment: Can you try the command in Terminal : `curl http://localhost` ?

Comment: it returns the html chunk : <html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>

Comment: Can you run the command in th answer with sudo ?

Comment: Nothing happens. Just a new line.